# Find Max Value and next highest two in Column using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy

I have a piece of code where I am able to find the max value. How can i edit this code to find the second largest, and then the third? I found this code here (https://geonet.esri.com/message/237880#237880). While there is another method that identifies a way to do this, it appears like it would be much slower (bulid array, sort, and pull [-1])

```
myField = "MY_FIELD"  
minValue = arcpy.SearchCursor(inlayer, "", "", "", myField + " A").next().getValue(myField) #Get 1st row in ascending cursor sort  
maxValue = arcpy.SearchCursor(inlayer, "", "", "", myField + " D").next().getValue(myField) #Get 1st row in descending cursor sort
```

Answer (score 3):

Building on @Richard's comments, let's see which is the quickest way.

Short answer:

- **`sorted()`** Not surprising, haha.

---

Too much time on my hands answer:

For starters, here's a table in an FGDB that was filled like so:

```
from random import randint
with arcpy.da.InsertCursor("d", "r") as cursor:
     for _ in xrange(1000000):
         cursor.insertRow([randint(0,1000)])
```

And here's our setup script. We'll take a look at:

- reading the data as is, for the baseline
- reading the data with a sql clause set to `ORDER BY _ DESC`
- reading the data as is, then sorting with Python
- for fun, let's see how SQL Server 2014 handles it

.

```
import timeit

disk = '''
import arcpy
table = r''
sql_1 = (None, 'ORDER BY r DESC')
'''

mem = '''
import arcpy
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput=True
t = r''
table = arcpy.CopyRows_management(t, 'in_memory/d')
sql_1 = (None, 'ORDER BY r DESC')
'''

sde = '''
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = r''
table = ''
sql_1 = ('TOP 3', 'ORDER BY r DESC')
'''

print("From disk")
print(min(timeit.repeat("[row[0] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(table, 'r')][0:3]", setup=disk, repeat=10, number=1)))
print("From disk - sql_clause")
print(min(timeit.repeat("[row[0] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(table, 'r', sql_clause=sql_1)][0:3]", setup=disk, repeat=10, number=1)))
print("From disk - Python sort")
print(min(timeit.repeat("sorted([row[0] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(table, 'r')], reverse=True)[0:3]", setup=disk, repeat=10, number=1)))

print("From memory")
print(min(timeit.repeat("[row[0] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(table, 'r')][0:3]", setup=mem, repeat=10, number=1)))   
print("From memory - Python sort")
print(min(timeit.repeat("sorted([row[0] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(table, 'r')], reverse=True)[0:3]", setup=mem, repeat=10, number=1)))

print("SQL anyone?")
print(min(timeit.repeat("[row[0] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(table, 'r', sql_clause=sql_1)]", setup=sde, repeat=10, number=1)))
```

And the printout:

```
From disk
4.7289122002
From disk - sql_clause
19.5422670932 # Yikes!
From disk - Python sort
5.11995715052
From memory
0.242351783362
From memory - Python sort
0.565322884299
SQL anyone?
0.0572638263781 # Wowie!
```

So what's the takeaway from all this?

- SSD is still orders of magnitude slower than RAM

  - ~20x slower just reading data from disk
- `sql_clause` vs. Python's `sorted()`

  - ~4x slower when reading from disk
  - can't test on `in_memory` workspace (not supported)
- Unsurprisingly, the SQL `TOP` clause is very fast

  - ~10x better than everything else

So long answer short, the `in_memory` workspace helps out drastically with read speeds. Once it's in "Python's memory", sorting is very fast.

Comment: For the `TOP` option, any reason to use `TOP 3` as opposed to `TOP 1` (besides it not really making much of a difference)?

Comment: @EmilBrundage because OP wanted the three largest.

Answer (score 1):

```
sortAsc= arcpy.SearchCursor(inlayer, "", "", "", myField + " A") #Sorted in ascending order

first = sortAsc.next().getValue(myField) 
second = sortAsc.next().getValue(myField)
third = sortAsc.next().getValue(myField)
```

Try this, each time you call .next(), it should move the cursor so you just keep calling .next() to go through the table.

Comment: I won't use the old style cursors any more, because they are so slow and with sorting they are unusable for large datasets.  I only use da cursors.  I would use list comprehension of a search cursor into a list, sort the list and then loop through the list or verify list length and use list index positions to get each ordered value.  values = [row[0] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, (field))] -> sorted(values, reverse=True) -> for loop

Comment: You are wrong that array or list sorting is slower.  In memory sorting is much faster than sorting a cursor, since lists and arrays are in memory.  Reading ordered records from the database is always slower.

Comment: +1 @RichardFairhurst also worth considering TableToNumpyArray

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution with a little thinking... Ignore the first while loop, other code for other reasons....

```
cur_vals = 2
neighbour = 0
        while neighbour == 0:
            cur_val = cur_vals
            row = arcpy.SearchCursor("CONFLICT.shp", "", "", "", "RNDM" + " D")
            while 1 <= cur_val:
                xx = row.next().getValue("RNDM")
                print xx
                cur_val -= 1
```